Mojave install is impossible
It is not possible to install Ubuntu on a flash drive from Mojave.

Methods involving using the Terminal don't work
BelinaEtcher before 1-5-16 will not run
BelinaEtcher 1-5-16 and 1-5-17 run but produce junk on the flash drive
Using BelinaEtcher ruins the flash drive making it non-working
The flash drive ruined by BelinaEtcher can NOT be repaired using Disk Utility
I have tried installing Ubuntu 24.04.1 and 24.10 neither install correctly even though BelinaEtcher 1-15-16 and 1-5-17 installs those Ubuntu distros normally
Nowhere on the Internet can I find "Install Ubuntu For Mac Mojave"

Result Screen After Choosing Ubuntu During Option + Boot



Did you verify the checksums of the ISO? 2. We need to determine if this is a Mac issue or an issue specific to the ISO. Did you try booting the drive in another PC?

